# How to clear the saved password and username for text box?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have saved the User Name and Password during the log-in in my site. But when I use a password text box anywhere within the site, my User Name and Password gets automatically filled up. I've tried

```
AutoComplete="Disabled"
```

and also

```
TextPassword.text=string.Empty.
```

But these commands aren't working.

Comment: Are you sure it's the code that's pre-filling these values and not the web browser?  The application can't control what the web browser does.

Comment: Could you supply example code that reproduces the error?  This isn't much to go on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the browser auto-filling these fields, not your site.  Disable it in the browser.

The same might happen with address and email fields.